# How to remove deleted records from salesforce database memory?

Tags: database, recycle-bin, recycle

3 days back I have created a report in my org and after some times I deleted that record ..even i deleted report from recycle bin as well

Now it's been 3 days still that report present in salesforce database

when query with all rows in execute anonymous, soql returning report details

[image]

check the created date and it is deleted but still this is in memory..

A way tried by myself. I created 25 K Account records and deleted those records, also deleted from recycle bin

I thought hope this may delete my reports from salesforce database  but no :( this report is still in memory..

Looks like I need to wait till 15 days to remove from back end database.

because of this I am unable to create another report with same unique name.

I know if I change the report name it will work but in my case I need to create report with same unique name because of lightning badge :(

Comment: how about undelete the report.. change api name of the report to something else.  And create a new report with the desired report name?

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy good point but we can't perform undelete DML on Report object.

Comment: Oh yea, forgot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you delete records from the Recycle bin they still persist in the database for an indeterminate amount of time. Salesforce says 15 days, but I have seen records stay in for much longer than that.

I had an issue with one of our clients at a previous employer around this exact issue. After weeks of being on the phone with the client and Salesforce the issue finally escalated to tier 3 support.

**How the delete process works (from tier 3 support):**

> Each Salesforce instance has a 'sweeper' thread that goes through the database(s) and removes records from tables that are in a deleted status. There is no first deleted first removed to this process. So records can remain on the table long after you have deleted and removed them from the recycle bin.

If you need to get something hard deleted Saleseforce can do that for you if you have the proper level of support. But speaking from experience, it can take quite a while to get to the level of support that can do that for you.

I know this probably isn't the answer you are looking for, but figured I would share my experience with this.

Comment: Are you quoting documentation there? Can you link to it?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Unfortunately no. This how the tier 3 support team explained to us that it worked 'under the covers'.

Comment: Ah, but you're still quoting someone? Can you at least `> blockquote` what comes from an official source so it's more clear (and maybe make a tad more explicit where it came from)? +1 from me, it looks like a great explanation, I just think it's hard to tell who said what.

Comment: @AdrianLarson is that a bit clearer?

Comment: Much, thanks! Love seeing your contributions on here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the problem here is deleting a report not records being reported... I've not had a problem with deleting records and emptying the recycle bin.

The error message you get when you have deleted a report and want to re-use the "Report Unique Name" is:

> Error: This Report Unique Name already exists or has been previously
>   used. Please choose a different name.

I take the "previously used" part to include ones that have been created and deleted. So you can re-use the label but have to pick a new "Report Unique Name" e.g. append "2" to the end of it.

Presumably this design decision was made for a reason but I don't know what that reason is.

Comment: Keith C..  thanks for your concern.. I love to change the report name.. but i have to create report with name inorder to get the lightning superbadge... :(

Comment: @Ratan Think you are facing one of those situations where a limitation in one part of the platform is OK most of the time but is occasionally a huge pain. Don't know what the support model is for what you are doing but may need a human being to sort out. (Seems like the automation that checks your work ought to base its naming on the label not the unique name.)

Comment: Keith C... yes.. now I'm just waiting when the report deleted from backend so i could create new report with same unique name.. I guess it will take 15 days to delete from salesforce database

Comment: @Ratan My assumption is you will _never_ be able to re-use the name but that is just my assumption.